# Connections on Tor constantly timing out

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I recently just downloaded the Tor browser bundle {FireFox Version ESR 24.60.0}

I seem to be able to connect to the network, however I cannot connect to any hidden service, or normal clear net site. I only get notifications that the connection keeps timing out. I know that this is a non-elaborate question however, this is a recurring issue that I cannot seem to mitigate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I did do ample research and I cannot seem to find anything helpful and have uninstalled Bitdefender antivirus to no avail.

Comment: Why do you say that you can connect to the network? Can you connect to https://check.torproject.org/?

Comment: Do you live in an area with some kind of internet restriction? Does your ISP or Web administrator restrict internet access in anyway? Try pluggable transport and verify if Tor works in this mode.

Comment: @mirimir, by saying that I connect to the network, I mean that I can successfully launch the bundle package and access the browser which states that I am connected to the Tor network ( you can now browse web annon etc..) However I cannot navigate past this page, every connection afterwards times out consistently.

Comment: @Roya, no I am not located in an area which restricts net access at all. And have used Tor previously.

Comment: Mac OS and Sophos antivirus software?
https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#SophosOnMac

Comment: It is indeed Mac OS, however no Sophos antivirus. I have tried checking with my other antivirus software and it does not have Tor or its folders blocked. Should i uninstall Tor and reinstall it in a different folder ?

Comment: @Macedon93 The current Tor browser doesn't actually connect to https://check.torproject.org/. If you can't load that website, you aren't connected. Download a new copy of Tor Browser, and try again. Follow the instructions: "Download the file above, save it somewhere, then click on it. Mac OS X will automatically unarchive it and you will have a TorBrowser application in your chosen language. (e.g. TorBrowser_en-US.app) ... Click the TorBrowser application to launch Tor Browser."

Comment: @mirimir, thanks for the advice. Ill do so now.(Should i uninstall my current version ? Or save over the file.) Also i just tried to log into check.torproject.org and the connection has also timed out.

Comment: @Macedon93 I don't know Macs. But this seems to be the answer: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/318/how-do-i-keep-my-tor-browser-bundle-current.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the green onion and select "Open Network Settings". Click on "Copy Tor Log To Clipboard". Paste clipboard in reply here. Report your antivirus and firewall software.

Comment: 6/29/14, 18:24:48.986 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. 
6/29/14, 18:24:50.133 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit. 
6/29/14, 18:24:50.646 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
6/29/14, 18:24:50.646 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done. 
6/29/14, 18:24:52.117 [NOTICE] New control connection opened.

Comment: Antivirus Software is Bitdefender.

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs you've provided - it's 100% clear that problem is in your software setup. To diagnose Tor's problems you should look for two strings to make 101% sure that there's no problem with Tor itself:

> 6/29/14, 18:24:50.646 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.

and

> 6/29/14, 18:24:50.646 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.

Fitst one tells you that **everything is OK** and even without finishing a full bootstrap Tor is able to serve client connections and requests *from this very moment*. Second one confirms that *every bootstrapping and initialization procedure has been completed successfully*. If you have these two messages in your Tor log and no further errors in it - the Tor is not to blame in any connection problem, it's working and it's OK. Looks like your AV software or a browser plug-in is interfering with your connection *from your local browser instance to your local Tor instance*. That's where the problem is in your case. Try to uninstall your AV program - yes, you heared it right. Some AV's are all-the-stuff-in-one now, and even setting it to "Disabled" or "Inactive" state has no full effect described: i.e. local firewall and browsing filter are to blame in your particular case. I've seen it with Kasperskiy's products - you can disable it totally, *but it still bugs you*. So - try to remove it. If you need it on your host, you need to tune up a firewall, browser filtering *and application control* parts to trust and enable Tor process and Tor browser executable as well.